# Does xmlTreeParse file argument can take paths only in Home Directory

Tags: r, xml-parsing

str(xmlTreeParse)
function (file, ignoreBlanks = TRUE,....

xmlTreeParse Documentation of 'file' argument reads :

file
The name of the file containing the XML contents. This can contain \~ which is expanded to the user's home directory. It can also be a URL. See isURL. Additionally, the file can be compressed (gzip) and is read directly without the user having to de-compress (gunzip) it.

Does this mean it can read xml files only from home directory?

Background :
I was facing an issue :
Error: XML content does not seem to be XML

for the code :

```
fileName <- "C:/Users/Sharvari/Desktop/Coursera/Getting and Cleaning 
             Data/test.xml"
```

xmlTreeParse(fileName, asText = TRUE)
   Error: XML content does not seem to be XML: ' 
   C:/Users/Sharvari/Desktop/Coursera/Getting and Cleaning Data/test.xml'

I read the documentation and copied and pasted the same file into exampleData of home directory of RStudio.

```
fileName <- system.file("exampleData", "get.xml", package="XML")
fileName
[1] "C:/Users/Sharvari/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/XML/exampleData/get.xml"
xmlTreeParse(fileName)
```

This works fine.
Can you tell me what's going on here?

Find "get.xml" [here](https://github.com/SharvariGC/datasciencecoursera/blob/master/get.xml).